# Why does my app crashes while implementing button?

Tags: java, android, crash

Here is the code...whenever I launch the app on my phone it just crashes. I'm new to android programming so please help me. After doing some tests it comes out the problem is when I asssign the value to Value1 and Value2(just a guess). please help me out here. Thanks in advance.
MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.add;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText num1;
    EditText num2;
    Button add;
    TextView ans;
    int Value1;
    int Value2;
    int result;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        num1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
        num2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);
        Value1 = Integer.parseInt(num1.getText().toString());
        Value2 = Integer.parseInt(num2.getText().toString());
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
        ans = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                result = Value1 + Value2;

                ans.setText(""+result);


            }

        });
    }

}
```

and the activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.add.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:hint="Number 1"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/et1"
        android:inputType="number"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et1"
        android:hint="Number 2"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/et2"
        android:inputType="number"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/addBtn"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et2"
        android:text="Add"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Your Answer"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/addBtn"
        android:id="@+id/tv"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Share error log.

Comment: Please share your log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logic is : get edit text value on click listener of Button

```
 add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         try{
        Value1 = Integer.parseInt(num1.getText().toString());
        Value2 = Integer.parseInt(num2.getText().toString());
        result = Value1 + Value2;
            result = Value1 + Value2;

            ans.setText(""+result);
        }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
           Log.e("Exc",e.toString());      
     }


        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the value before it inserted,you have to get value when user click on add button and get value1 and value2 inside `onClickListner`

change according to this

```
package com.example.android.add;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText num1;
EditText num2;
Button add;
TextView ans;
int Value1;
int Value2;
int result;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    num1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
    num2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);

    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
    ans = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Value1 = Integer.parseInt(num1.getText().toString());
            Value2 = Integer.parseInt(num2.getText().toString());

            result = Value1 + Value2;

            ans.setText(""+result);


        }

    });
   }
 }
```

Comment: Don't just dump code: explain the problem, explain the change.

Answer (score 1):

```
Value1 = Integer.parseInt(num1.getText().toString());
Value2 = Integer.parseInt(num2.getText().toString());
```

this code write into `onClick()` method.remove from `onCreate()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your code to this and it should run. The problem is you are accessing the values in `EditText`s too early, even before you type any in them. You need to access these values in `onClick()` of your `add` button

```
package com.example.android.add;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText num1;
    EditText num2;
    Button add;
    TextView ans;
    int Value1;
    int Value2;
    int result;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        num1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
        num2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);

        // If you get value from edit texts here it will cause an error 
        // since onCreate is called at the very beginning and you have not 
        // entered any value in num1 and num2.

        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
        ans = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            // Instead put them here so you have already inserted values 
            // into the fields before they are retrieved:

            Value1 = Integer.parseInt(num1.getText().toString());
            Value2 = Integer.parseInt(num2.getText().toString());

            result = Value1 + Value2;

            ans.setText(""+result);

            }

        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using OnClickListeners for button is discouraged. It has been replaced with the XML Attribute: `android:onClick = "functionName"`.

And this function is to be implemented in the Activity to which the layout file is attached to. Hence, in `MainActivity.java`:

`public void funcitonName(View v){
// your code here
}`

Answer (score 0):

There may be a number of string conversion error

```
Value1 = 0;

try {
    Value1 = Integer.parseInt(num1.getText().toString());
} catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
   System.out.println("Could not parse " + nfe);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app is crashing because of these two lines

```
Value1 = Integer.parseInt(num1.getText().toString());
Value2 = Integer.parseInt(num2.getText().toString());
```

here you are trying to convert string to integer where string is null if editText doesnt have ant values these type of error occur while typeCasting so add validation before typeCasting like below

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        num1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
        num2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
        ans = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(num1.getText() != null && num2.getText() != null) {
                    Value1 = Integer.parseInt(num1.getText().toString());
                    Value2 = Integer.parseInt(num2.getText().toString());
                    result = Value1 + Value2;

                    ans.setText("" + result);
                }


            }

        });
    }
```